# Problem with custom layout in Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have tried my level best but unable to solve my problem - now requesting you experts to help me out.  the sample code and screen shot is enclosed for better understanding.

what i want and unable to achieve that i want column 2.3 to appear under column 2.1 on desktop and under 2.2 on mobile devices (on mobile 2.1 is already appearing on top of 2.2 and 2.3, which is correct)

I need help to get 2.3 floated/pushed under 2.1. Thank you very much for your help.

[image]

```html
<div class="container p-4 p-sm-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-auto bg-light border rounded pt-2 d-none d-sm-block mr-4">
            <h1>1.1</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="dashboard-header" class="col ss-tutor-header rounded">
                    <h1>1.2</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-auto order-1 order-sm-2 bg-light border rounded">
                    <h1>2.1</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col order-2 order-sm-1 bg-light border rounded">
                    <h1>2.2</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-auto order-3 order-sm-3 bg-light border rounded">
                    <h1>2.3</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-auto order-1 order-sm-2 bg-light border rounded">
                    <h1>3.1</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col order-2 order-sm-1 bg-light border rounded">
                    <h1>3.2</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here is to add an invisible block (100% width but 0 height) before 2.3 at `md` break point and up, and reverse the direction of that row so that it goes from left to right:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-auto ...">1.1</div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="dashboard-header" class="col ...">
                1.2
            </div>
            <div class="row **flex-md-row-reverse**">
                <div class="col-md-auto ... order-1 order-sm-2 **order-md-1**...">
                    2.1
                </div>
                <div class="col order-2 order-sm-1 **order-md-2** ...">
                    2.2
                </div>
                **<div class="d-none d-md-block order-md-3 invisible-block" />**
                <div class="col-md-auto order-3 **order-md-4** ...">
                    2.3
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                ...
            <div>
        </div>
    <div>
</div>
```

Hopefully it's not hard to read and tell the changes I added (I "highlighted" them). In order to break 2.3 to a new line, you really need an element that takes up 100% width to force so.

That's why I set up a css class that takes up 100% width but 0 height:

```css
.invisible-block {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
}
```

And in order to put 2.3 under 2.1 at `md` break point, you do need to reverse the row direction: from right to left. Hence you need to reset the order for 2.1 and 2.2 at `md` break point.

[image: At mediun]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/hq04g2fa/39/

#### Update: if 2.3 has to be floating on the right of 2.2 under 2.1

Per OP author's comment that 2.3 needs to be floating on the right of 2.2 when 2.2's content overflows vertically.

This wouldn't be possible without changing the structure and duplicating at least 2.1:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-auto ...">1.1</div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="dashboard-header" class="col ...">
                1.2
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-auto **d-sm-none** ...">
                    2.1
                </div>
                <div class="col ...">
                    2.2
                    Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-auto">
                    **<div class="row">
                        <div class="d-none d-sm-block col-12 ...">
                            2.1 Copy
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 ...">
                            2.3
                        </div>
                    </div>**
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                ...
            <div>
        </div>
    <div>
</div>
```

You need to display 2.1 and 2.3 as columns in a row, which is wrapped by the outter column so that when 2.2 overflows vertically, 2.3 will stay under 2.1 and on the right of 2.2.

But since at `sm` break point the order of 2.1 and 2.2 switches, there is no way to do so because 2.1 is wrapped inside another row nested inside the column.

[image]

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/hq04g2fa/60/

Comment: It's working fine to me: https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/hq04g2fa/42/. When you add content to 2.2, of course it will grow vertically but it didn't break in my opinion. What did you mean by "things broke-up completely"?

Comment: Hello @David Liang, thank you so much for your time and effort. I really appreciate it from the core of my heart. Initially your solution seemed to be working but when i added some content to 2.2 and it grew vertically the 2.3 should  be floating on the right of 2.2 under 2.1 instead of empty space under the content of 2.1

**Yes you are right. i made a mistake which was the reason of things breaking up.**



I am extremely sorry if this was not clear in my initial question.

demo: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/0j8efsc1/)

Comment: If that's the case, you would have to either set a fixed with to the left elements, or duplicate 2.1 and 2.3 and make them within a column for certain break points. There is no way to get it working with my method.

Comment: Thank you David. I appreciate your feedback :)

Comment: @AmerHamid: please see my update. I showed how to do it with duplicating just 2.1. With that you can get rid of the orderings so it's actually not that bad.

Comment: David, I must say that you are brilliant. i loved the work-around. you are the man! :) A million thanks.